# vectorize a for loop which searches for similar strings

Tags: python, numpy

I have two lists, let's say listA and listB which contain strings names(first and last name). Both lists contains over 2000 elements and I am trying to find similar string names. A for loop that compare each element would be like below.

```
threshold = 90

response = []
for name_to_find in listA:
            resp_match =  process.extractOne(str(name_to_find) ,listB) #listB can work as pd.Series as well
        if resp_match[1] > threshold:
             row = {'items_listA':name_to_find,'items_listB':resp_match[0], 'score':resp_match[1]}
             response.append(row)
         print(row)
```

I hope that if I vectorize the process will take less time to run. Does a Levenshtein distance process needed for making this loop running faster?

Comment: How do you define "similar"?  If you were looking for an exact match, you could sort the two lists and run through them in parallel.  For "similarity", there's no shortcut; you have to examine every pair.  `itertools.combinations` can help with that.

Comment: `numpy` "vectorizing" means using compiled `numpy` methods - ones that operate on whole arrays.  The arrays may be 1d, like lists, and the result may be 2d, like an outer product (e.g. imagine a multiplication table).  Most work with numeric values, doing addition, multiplications, inequality testing etc.  String methods are limited, basically just equality.  So you may have to convert your strings to some sort of numeric encoding,  I see posts asking a NLP (natural language processing) in numpy/scipy/sklearn, but haven't paid much attention to them.